# Trigger and its test class

Tags: trigger, unit-test, account, contact

I am new to Salesforce. I have written a trigger to update contact based on account  field. The Trigger code is below.

```
trigger Update_contact_based_on_acc on Account (before update) {
    List<contact> cont = new List<contact>();
    for(Account acc : Trigger.new){
        if(acc.Type == 'Prospect'){
            Contact con = new contact();
            con.AccountId = acc.Id;
            con.FirstName = acc.Name;
            con.LastName = acc.Phone;
            cont.add(con);
        }
    }
    if(cont.size()>0){
        insert cont; 
    }
}
```

I want to use `System.assert,System.AssertEquals,Test.start,test.stop and system.runas` to clear my concept. So how can I use these in my test class which is attached below?

```
@isTest
public class Update_contact_based_on_accTest {
    public static testmethod void PrimaryAccountTest(){

        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'Test';
        acc.Type = 'Prospect';
        insert acc; 

        acc.Phone = '8404868903';
        update acc;

        contact con = new contact(FirstName='accnmame',LastName='test',
                                  AccountId=acc.Id);
        insert con; 
        system.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your trigger is creating a new Contact whenever _any_ change is made to Account.

Answer (score 1):

A good pattern to follow when writing a testmethod is the Given-When-Then pattern

```
// Given a mock Account

// When Account Updated

// Then Verify Contact created
```

then fill in the details

```
// Given a mock Account
Account mockAccount = new Account(...);
insert mockAccount

// When Account Updated
Test.startTest();
update mockAccount;
Test.stopTest();

// Then Verify Contact created
Contact[] results = [SELECT ... FROM Contact];
System.assertEquals(1,results.size(),'sb 1 Contact per mockAccount');
System.assertEquals(mockAccount.Phone,results[0].LastName,'mockAccount phone becomes Contact LastName');
...
```

Of course, as this is a trigger, you should test with collections and, if record sharing/CRUD is a concern for certain profiles/permissionSets, then use the `System.runAs(..)` block to test those dependencies as well (as shown by Rashmi S's answer).

Trailhead is your best resource for testmethods and a [deeper dive can be found here on StackExchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-qa)

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger creates a new contact when Account is updated and if type = 'Prospect'

```
@isTest
public class Update_contact_based_on_accTest {
    public static testmethod void PrimaryAccountTest(){

        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'Test';
        acc.Type = 'Prospect';
        insert acc; 


        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Prof1'];
        User u = new User(Alias = 'usr', Email='usr@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='test', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
                            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='wqutest');

        System.runAs(u) {

            test.startTest();
            acc.Phone = '8404868903';
            update acc;
            test.stopTest();
        }
        contact objContact = [select firstname, lastname from Contact where AccountId = acc.Id ];

        system.assertEquals( 'Test', objContact.FirstName);
    }
}
```

**system.assertEquals:** Matches with expected and actual value. If bote are equal, test passes else fails. 
**system.assert:** Ex: system.assert(x==y, "value matches");- if value of x is equal to y, it displays "value matches"
**Test.startTest()** and **Test.stopTest()** - this us used to get the fresh governor limit. For example if your class makes 90 SOQL queries before it calls startTest, you can make additional 100 SOQL within this.
**system.runas** - is used when you want to check the part of functionality for specific profile user.